# Another font identification question

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking to identify the font used in the logo [found here](http://themes.premiumpixels.com/?theme=stacked):

[image: blog logo]

I tried several online tools without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coffee Service by Stuart Sandler:

http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/sideshow/coffee-service/