# what Font used by sharpedgeIT company?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I was just wondering if anyone could find this font for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually is not single font i think so....as per my knowledge the logotypo is the combination of three fonts.... in logo

'sharp' is used Vox Round Wide SemiBold

'edge' is used Sol Pro Medium from Canada Type

'IT' is used Tanseek Modren Pro Medium

these are the closely match of that logo....[image]

Comment: sol pro is sufficiently close IMHO.

Comment: @llan i also think so

Comment: By the way Rachuru, I'm curious. *How the heck did you figure out that three different fonts were used in that logo??*

Comment: @JonathanTodd by using online http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ searching by full logo i got the  Vox Wide SemiBold from Canada Type Vox similar....for "sharp" it is similar closed...but edge is different so guessed that for "edge" they used another font i sliced the logo into three images sharp,edge & IT then i  searched so i got similar fonts...

Comment: I disagree that it's 3 typefaces. The "p" and "d" are identical other than rotation, they aren't different typefaces.

Answer (score 3):

We enjoy answering your design questions, we really do. However, we're no more capable than you are of finding the name of a font. Rather than being an intellectual question that we can answer for you, it's merely a chore.

However, in good faith, I've searched a (kinda close) match to your font for you: **[Vox Wide SemiBold from Canada Type Vox](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/canadatype/vox/wide-semibold/)**

It might not be the perfect match, but if you want a more precise match, you may need to do some manual searching.

Please see:

- [How can I automatically determine fonts used in an image or PDF?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf).
- [How to manually identify a font when the automatic services fail?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/how-to-manually-identify-a-font-when-the-automatic-services-fail/4117#4117)

---

As a final note, remember, as some good logos use private or modified fonts, it may not be possible to find an exact match, no matter what you do.

Comment: thanks for the ans but still it's not accurate .The e is diffrent

Comment: @Sumann Agreed, but it's probably the closest you'll get without spending an hour or more browsing the web.

Comment: yes i know ,i appreciate your hard work still i need exact version .

Comment: +1 This is the right answer (complete with caveat that the ***e*** is a custom variant).