# What is the name of this sans-serif typeface?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I want to use font in image **"attached"** but don't know what is it's name so that I can search over internet. 
Tell me if anybody knows the answer.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/how-to-manually-identify-a-font-when-the-automatic-services-fail/4117#4117 for useful resources on font-identification.

Comment: It would probably help if you added a link to where the image can be found.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I tried but couldn't find it...

Comment: Please look at our Font guidelines http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions - note that if you can't provide any sort of title or source as to where you found the image then it does nobody else any good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very similar to [MB Picture House](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/m-b-creative/mb-picture-house/) — clues are the M not touching the baseline; points at vertices; low cross-bar on the E; high centre on the S.

[image: MB Picture House]

Negative indicators are: that particular cut of the font doesn't have lower-case letters; the cross-bar of G may not be an identical match; the cross-bar of A may be a little high.

[Aside: *feasibility* is spelled wrongly in the image.]

Comment: Thanks but it isn't actually same as in picture. You have pointed to some letters which aren't similar font as in image but to tell you, "A" letter really attracted me so that why I wanted to use it but font you have provided as common "A" letter . If you know its name tell me. Again thanks for sharing... :)

Comment: About the wrong spelling! It isn't by image image. I just found it over internet..

Answer (score 7):

Please look at the [NEUTRA family](http://www.houseind.com/search/?search=neutra) fonts, probably this family contains one of the fonts which is close to the font in the question.

[image]

+

[image]

Comment: Yep. I think this is correct!

Comment: It is definitely correct; I've added my +1. (But my suggestion isn't all that far off and may still be useful to consider)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks. Yes, your answer is close... I just remembered that already met the font with so special AHE letters...

Answer (score 1):

Identifont to the rescue!

[Use this wizard to find candidates yourself](http://www.identifont.com/filter?1+TECHNOLGYBUSIMADV)

EDIT:
Identifont is a website which lets you identify fonts by asking a series of questions. It even has a function to base the questions on a restricted set of characters (as is the case here, we don't know what other letters look like). The URL i provided already has the graphs' subset setup for you. Answer the questions, and you'll be given a list of fonts that meet your demands.

Comment: Welcome to GD.  Your answer may help the OP but do you mind explaining a little more about your link since link only answers from new users tend to receive more downvotes and flagged as spam and if your link were to ever go down we will delete your answer